# Realtime graph using JFreeChart and displaying in JSP

Tags: jsp, real-time, jfreechart

I'm trying to plot the system CPU utilization in a JSP page.

I'm using JFreeChart library to do so, I have a problem,

The generation of the graph I've written in a Servlet and that generates an image, so on the JSP page it flickers and reloads the image.

Is there a better way to implement it as I want to see a continuous flowing graph and not an image?

NOTE: I'm using ajax call to the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java Applet
2. Flash
3. A Javascript plotting library maybe (such as [this](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) or [this](http://processingjs.org/learning/custom/molten))
4. Something else I haven't thought of

Comment: like your style of answering. Applet, out of the question, Flash, not sure since the product would be running on Mac-Safari. Shall look @ the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is a Java Web Start application that queries the servlet for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to delivering the chart as an applet, say as outlined [here](http://patrickwebster.blogspot.com/2009/01/scalable-jfreechart-applet.html)?